# Update/Merge with Duplicates in Destination Table (Oracle 11g)

Tags: oracle11g, merge, duplicates

I’ve been struggling with this one for while, would appreciate some advice. A bit context about the source and destination tables involved in the update/merge query I'm using:

```
SRC Table

Format_Code     ACR
----------------------------
BAD             5  
SAD             7
MAD             2
```

SRC is created via a select statement joining on two tables; select statement looks something like this:

```
Select distinct a.Format_Code, b.ACR from Formats a
Inner join Codes b on lower(a.Format_Name) = lower(b.Format_Name)
```

I’m attempting to use SRC to update a destination table (DES), joining/matching on Format_Code as follows:

```
Merge Into Inventory DES
Using
(
Select distinct a.Format_Code, b.ACR from Formats a
Inner join Codes b on lower(a.Format_Name) = lower(b.Format_Name)
) SRC
On DES.Format_Code = SRC.Format_Code
When Matched Then Update set DES.ACR = SRC.ACR
```

I get the following error (because of the duplicates in the destination table I think) but not sure how to ignore/bypass them. SRC contains no duplicates but DES does have duplicate Format_Code. During the update I’d like to either update just one instance of the duplicate rows or ignore duplicates entirely (small number of duplicates so I can update manually if necessary)

```
SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
*Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
*Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.
```

It’s my first time posting, so apologies if I’ve made any rookie mistakes

Comment: Are you sure these are all actually tables, not views - with one referencing the others? Or that there are no triggers on any of them? It seems to work OK with simple tables. Maybe [create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can replicate what you're seeing.

Comment: Yes the SRC 'tables' are in fact views, it turns out that one of these views is referencing the same table as I'm trying to update. I've captured the results of the SRC query in a table and then referred this in my Merge statement, which has worked. Thanks for your help Alex

Answer (score 0):

> ... because of large dml activity ...

Try to `COMMIT`, and then run your `MERGE`. Any improvement?